# Spring Security, Boot: Security Rules not working as excepted

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-boot, spring-security

I am very new to spring boot and I am trying to implement spring security and session management using spring boot in my application.

### My questions are as follows

1. how do i restrict direct page access from static folder without logging into application ?
   Example: localhost:8080/view/pages/[blank.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SP7YV.png)
2. Do i need to add any additional configuration to achieve session management? Also how to identify session got created or not for the particular login user?

The spring security version that I use is 1.5.3.RELEASE. can anyone please tell me how i can achieve spring security rules and session management. Thanks in advance for helping

Following is my code added in security config class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()      
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/homePage")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()    
        .and()
                    .sessionManagement()
                    .maximumSessions( 1 )
                    .expiredUrl( "/sessionExpired" )
                    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin( true )
                    .and()
                        .sessionCreationPolicy( SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception 
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a question. Also describe what the result of your code is (maybe output if needed)

Comment: I have modified my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to tell what is happening, try to enable logging

```
org.springframework.security: trace
org.springframework.web: trace
```

and post what is printed when you make request

Answer (score -1):

Try this code, and here the "ADMIN" is a role. It can be "ROLE_ADMIN" in spring, based on how you want to configure the roles.

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/login.html", "/logout.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/index.html").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")      .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login.html").failureUrl("/login.html").defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html")
        .usernameParameter("strUserName").passwordParameter("strPassword")
    .and().csrf()
    .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/404");
```